# ID of the closest element to a point - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, wkwebview

I need - using javascript - to fetch the **id** of the closest element to a specific point (the top left corner of the visible frame). I can't use jquery or other frameworks unfortunately, so the solution must be in javascript.

I need it to run in a WKWebView on iOS.

I searched for similar questions, but all the solutions I've found were using jquery. :(

Thank you for your help, guys.

Comment: When you say "point" do you mean coordenades?

Comment: Can you post sample code or whatever you are trying to achieve through code?

Comment: - point I mean (x, y) coordinates
- I have no code because I have no idea how to achieve this result.

What I want to achieve: 

The user scroll the page. At some point he might decide to press a button from the UI (bookmark). My iOS app will query the script I'm asking here for the closest element with an id so that I can save for the bookmark `url#id`

Comment: Why not just save the scroll position in the hash, then have your script call `window.scrollTo` when you load the bookmark? Is this bookmark something that needs to be exportable to other browsers and still have this behavior?

Comment: Because on rotation, or on any reason for size changes of the webView, the scroll position is no longer valid. I used this approach in the past and it failed me. Also on device change, this approach is not a good one.

Comment: This isn't much better -- the only way I know to do it (since the element has to have an ID) is to iterate through all the elements (or maybe construct a k-d tree when the page opens), and there's no guarantee the page will have any elements with IDs anyways.

Comment: The pages are local on the device, so I can guarantee that it will have ids quite frequently within the page. I was thinking in mapping the page as well for id - position, but performance wise is an heavy operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.elementFromPoint`, e.g.:

```
var elem = document.elementFromPoint(0, 0);
```

Note that this will be relative to the viewport, not the document -- top left of the screen, not top left of the entire document. (I believe this is what you want anyways though.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for. elementFromPoint will return any element. I want the closest element that has an id, so that I can get its id.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza You mean a given ID? Or any element with any ID?

Comment: any element, with any id. The closest one to an x, y position